# Rotating Text on a scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

Using [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/WilliamQLiu/803b712a4d6efbf7bdb4), I have been able to create D3's scatter plot with text labels with the scatter points.

I would like to rotate each label to a certain degree, however, when I attempt to do this, all of the text as a whole is rotated on one axis, not individual axis`.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
        .attr('fill', '#4E5FF3')
        .attr('stroke', 'none')
        .attr('cx', d => { return x(Date.parse(d.date)) })
        .attr('cy', d => { return y(d.totalValue) })
        .attr('r', 3);
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
        .attr('x', d => { return x(Date.parse(d.date)) })
        .attr('y', d => { return y(d.totalValue) })
        .text(d => {
            return 'Total: ' + d.totalValue + ' - Month: ' + d.monthValue;
        })
        .attr('transform','rotate(5)translate(0, 0)');
```

How do I transform each label on an individual axis, rather than all of the labels on one axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a single value for `rotate`...

```
.attr('transform','rotate(5)translate(0, 0)');
```

...which will rotate the text around the origin (0,0), use the texts' positions in the `rotate` function, as the optional `x` and `y` parameters:

```
rotate(<a> [<x> <y>])
```

In the bl.ocks you linked, that would be (using commas):

```
.attr('transform',function(d){
    return "rotate(5," + xScale(d[0]) + "," + yScale(d[1]) + ")"
});
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/45fa2b852f8b0f229923c6dc1cdfa2b6/cf0917330d3d2775efd83a83c733c544d0338ea2